# Understanding Bash short-circuiting

Tags: linux, bash, short-circuiting

First of all I'm not a Bash pro. I discovered few months ago that if I use both the `&&` and `||` short circuit operators in sequence with curly braces, then in case the first statement exits with a truthful value, if the last statement in the true block exits non-zero, then the fail block will be executed too. Like this:

```
returnNumber 0 && {
    echo 'OK'
    returnNumber 1
} || {
    echo 'NG'
}
```

Will output:

```
OK
NG
```

So, I looked for the easiest solution for this, and came up with this:

```
returnNumber 0 && {
    echo 'OK'
    returnNumber 1
    :
} || {
    echo 'NG'
}
```

I know, it is easy to leave out the colon builtin, but is it a proper way for a workaround?

Comment: Do not make a sport out of using special syntax. When you just write `if-then-else-fi` most people will understand.  
Try to think of valid exceptions. I am still not sure about my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28478184/3220113 : it is effective but hard to read.

Comment: What kind of syntax are the curly braces in this context?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is actually a very common [Bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).  It is **not** a bug.

`returnNumber 0` evaluates to true, so the second block (joined by logical and `&&`) is evaluated as well to make sure the result of `first && second` is still true.
The second block outputs `OK` but evaluates to false, so now the result of `first && second` is false.  This means that the third portion (joined by logical or `||`) must be evaluated as well, causing `NG` to be displayed as well.

---

Instead of relying on `&&` and `||`, you should be using `if` statements:

```
if returnNumber 0; then
    echo 'OK'
    returnNumber 1
else
    echo 'NG'
fi
```

**tl;dr:** Never use `x && y || z` when `y` can return a non-zero exit status.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812984/658497 - Evaluating false condition with short-circuiting, will exit before reaching `&& command`. Use `[[ ! condition ]] || command` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Llama already corectly answered the question, this only for a quick reference what happens for different "combinations". The `cmd0` is an "command" with zero-exit status and the `cmd1` is with nonzero.

```
cmd0() { echo -n "[$@-0]"; return 0; }
cmd1() { echo -n "[$@-1]"; return 1; }
second() { echo "[second]"; }

doit() { echo "case: $@"; eval "$@"; echo; }

doit 'cmd0 start && cmd0 first && second'
doit 'cmd0 start && cmd0 first || second'
doit 'cmd0 start || cmd0 first && second'
doit 'cmd0 start || cmd0 first || second'

doit 'cmd0 start && cmd1 first && second'
doit 'cmd0 start && cmd1 first || second'
doit 'cmd0 start || cmd1 first && second'
doit 'cmd0 start || cmd1 first || second'

doit 'cmd1 start && cmd0 first && second'
doit 'cmd1 start && cmd0 first || second'
doit 'cmd1 start || cmd0 first && second'
doit 'cmd1 start || cmd0 first || second'

doit 'cmd1 start && cmd1 first && second'
doit 'cmd1 start && cmd1 first || second'
doit 'cmd1 start || cmd1 first && second'
doit 'cmd1 start || cmd1 first || second'
```

produces:

```
case: cmd0 start && cmd0 first && second
[start-0][first-0][second]

case: cmd0 start && cmd0 first || second
[start-0][first-0]

case: cmd0 start || cmd0 first && second
[start-0][second]

case: cmd0 start || cmd0 first || second
[start-0]

case: cmd0 start && cmd1 first && second
[start-0][first-1]

case: cmd0 start && cmd1 first || second
[start-0][first-1][second]

case: cmd0 start || cmd1 first && second
[start-0][second]

case: cmd0 start || cmd1 first || second
[start-0]

case: cmd1 start && cmd0 first && second
[start-1]

case: cmd1 start && cmd0 first || second
[start-1][second]

case: cmd1 start || cmd0 first && second
[start-1][first-0][second]

case: cmd1 start || cmd0 first || second
[start-1][first-0]

case: cmd1 start && cmd1 first && second
[start-1]

case: cmd1 start && cmd1 first || second
[start-1][second]

case: cmd1 start || cmd1 first && second
[start-1][first-1]

case: cmd1 start || cmd1 first || second
[start-1][first-1][second]
```